# How is this exactly a curried function?

Tags: scala, currying

I am reading Functional Programming in Scala, and going through different exericses. I encountered currying.

Can someone explain to me this curried function and how does this work? I can seem to understand this piece of code. compared to the ones I saw on different blogs regarding currying in Scala.

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) =  a => b => f(a,b)
```

is `a` from   a => b => f(a,b) a function if so what are its arguments?

Also update what does this mean?  `a` in `a => b => f(a,b)` means? is a function that will return a function named b that takes single parameter and will return a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you understand the concept of currying and that the type definition makes sense to you: `A => B => C`.

The implementation is: `a => b => f(a,b)`, you could read it as:

```
... = { a => 
        { b => 
          { f(a,b) }
        }
      }
```

So `a` is the parameter accepted as input of your function of type `A => (B => C)`. And this function returns a second function - of type `B => C`, that takes `b:B` and apply `f` to both.

Edit: you could use this very verbose version if it helps you understand:

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = {

  def aToBToC(a: A): B => C = {

    def bToC(b: B): C = {
      f(a,b)
    }

    bToC
  }

  aToBToC
}
```

See how I define private functions in nested scopes? (I haven't tried in the REPL, maybe there is a typo, but you get the idea.)

Comment: So what you are saying that A is parameter that's a function?

Comment: So what you are saying that 'a' is a function in the expression a => b => f(a,b)?

Comment: No, `a` is the first parameter of an anonymous function of type `A => (B => C` - it takes an `A` and returns a function of `B` to `C`. This is the idea of currying: instead of taking both a `A` and a `B` to make  a `C`, you take one parameter after the other. Maybe you are confused because the function is anonymous and doesn't have a name.

Comment: it returned a type mismatch, I see, it's anonymous function but i thought scala cannot infer parameter types?

Comment: I fixed the problem in the code snippet. Scala can infer type parameters in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a function *curry* which takes an another function as parameter. The return type of that function is `A => (B => C)`, also a function from `A` to `B => C`.

After that you defined a implementation of `A => (B => C)`, also for given `a` return a function `b => f(a,b)`.

**Example:**

```
def plus(a: Int, b:Int): Int = a + b
```

The curried version of `plus`:

```
scala> def plusC(a:Int): Int => Int = plus(a, _)
plusC: (a: Int)Int => Int

scala> plusC(1)
res4: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> res4(10)
res5: Int = 11
```

Comment: Little bit confused, so in the declaration, 'a => b => f(a,b)' 'a' is a function ?

Comment: No, 'a' is the first parameter of a return function. You can read 'a => b => f(a,b)' as: my function returns a function from 'a' with one parameter, which returns a second function 'b => f(a,b)' with one input parameter from 'b' (the parameter 'a' is fixed).

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a curried function. This is a curry method (note: function and methods are very distinct concepts in Scala), i.e. a method that *does* the currying. Its *return value* is a curried function; it takes in a function of two arguments and *returns* a curried function.

Answer (score 0):

`def curry[A,B,C]` is not curried function itself, it just shows how to convert function that takes two parameters `f: (A, B) => C` into the curried function `A => (B => C)`. `a => b => f(a, b)` means that function takes parameter `a` and returns function `b => f(a, b)`, which in its turn returns final value `f(a, b)`.